# ActiveAdmin csv partial override?

Tags: csv, customization, activeadmin

Is there a way to override the active admin csv partial? if not, is there a way to print columns refering not to an attribute but to a content? example:

in my model User i have the attribute :name but i dont want to print a row per each user.name, I want to print a Column for each User.name and asociate them in the next row with another attribute the name is "associated" with like their last_name so it could be like:

```
Name       Jhon     Adam      Chuck   etc..
LastName   Adams    Jhons      Guy
```

Comment: You want to output a transposed CSV where the columns become the rows, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to override the CSV's view template for specific models to transpose the data before generating the CSV output.

#### CSV View Template

With the assumption this is for the User model, create the following view file `app/views/admin/users/index.csv.erb`. It is important that the file is in the correct sub directory. With the default ActiveAdmin configuration the directory is `app/views/admin`.

```
<%-
  # This is a modification of the default index.csv.erb template found at:
  # https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.csv.erb

  require 'csv'

  default = active_admin_application.csv_options
  options = default.merge active_admin_config.csv_builder.options
  columns = active_admin_config.csv_builder.columns

  # Collect the data in an Array to be transposed.
  data = []
  data << columns.map(&:name)
  collection.each do |resource|
    data << columns.map do |column|
      call_method_or_proc_on resource, column.data
    end
  end

  csv_output = CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    data.transpose.each do |row|
      csv << row
    end
  end
%>
<%= csv_output.html_safe %>
```

#### ActiveAdmin Resource

You can now define your CSV normally in the ActiveAdmin User resource and the output will be transposed.

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  csv do
    column :id
    column :first_name
    column :last_name
  end
end
```

#### Output

```
Id,1,2
First Name,Alexis,Charles
Last Name,Carvajal,Maresh
```

Comment: This solution will not work as of April 13th. There is a pull request for this feature https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3410

Comment: This pull request, https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3038/files, removes the index.csv.erb template and causes the solution above not to work on the current ActiveAdmin (master branch / 1.0.0pre release). But it does continue to work for 0.6.x releases.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarifications. And yes, older versions are not effected.